# NUnit custom Command not calling into Execute()

Tags: nunit

I have created a custom `NUnit` attribute based on [this blog post](https://www.skyrise.tech/blog/tech/extending-nunit-3-with-command-wrappers/) (with but a few minor tweaks) which basically just returns a custom command. The command derives from `DelegatingTestCommand` and overrides `Execute` but `Execute` does not seem to be getting called. I am outputting to the test context and I never see the output. Minified code sample:

```
public class PrintingCommand : DelegatingTestCommand
{
    public PrintingCommand( TestCommand innerCommand )
        : base(innerCommand){}

    public override TestResult Execute( TestExecutionContext context )
    {
        context.OutWriter.WriteLine( "Hello output" );
        return context.CurrentResult;
    }
}


[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Method )]
public class PrintingAttribute : Attribute, IWrapSetUpTearDown
{
    public TestCommand Wrap( TestCommand command )
    {
        return new PrintingCommand( command );
    }
}
```

When I decorate a test with `[Printing]` I never see the `Hello output` written to anywhere.

This is a trivial example, in reality I am doing the retry stuff in the blog, which is not getting called/done wither.

Any ideas why?

Am using NUnit 3 & console runner at the command line.

Comment: I presume you made a typo, and you are actually decorating your test with `[Custom]`, not `[Printing]`?

Comment: @Chris gah, missed that! Have corrected the name of the attribute.

Comment: Can you copy what you're actually running? This must be missing bits as it wouldn't compile (e.g. Execute() doesn't return anything) - but I can't see anything obviously wrong with what's here.

Comment: And also maybe an example test you're running?

Comment: @Chris this is just a trivial-cut down example, my code is pretty much as-per that blog post (with the sole exception being that I am passing in an `Action` to be run in the case of failure, and then creating derived attributes which pass their own `Action`s in). The tests I am running are acceptance tests, they're using Selenium to test a UI but I do not see the output in any case. Have added correct `return` to this example now - basically just a proxy but I want to see the output to know that it is really running.

Comment: @Chris I have created a gist of my actual code if that is helpful https://gist.github.com/JackHerring/769dadb8ff2a8597c56a9e20e937c8e5

Comment: Have you tried applying FlakeyAttribute directly, rather than via FlakeyAcceptanceTestAttribute

Answer (score 1):

Your command never calls the inner command. Consequently, no test execution is ever completed. Look at the source for NUnit's own MaxTimeCommand to see how it might be done. Note that you can do things in your code both before and after the call to `innerCommand.Execute()`.

Having read the comments, I realize that your example may not match exactly what you are doing, but you we can really only give you answers about the code you show us.